# Firebase Authentication creates user but does not add their Info to database

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am new to using firebase and ios development in general. I am having an issue with adding user's info to the firestore database even though they are being added as authenticated users. Any Suggestions?

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, err) in
                if err != nil {
                    self.errorLabel.text = "Error Creating User"
                    self.errorLabel.alpha = 1
                } else {
                    let db = Firestore.firestore()

                    db.collection("users").addDocument(data: ["firstname":firstname, "lastname":lastname, "uid":result!.user.uid]) { (error) in

                        if error != nil {

                            self.errorLabel.text = "error saving user data"
                            self.errorLabel.alpha = 1
                        }
                    }

                    self.transitionScreens()

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error that u are having

Comment: @PeterHaddad that the users first and last name are not being added to the database even though the email and password are being registered as users

Comment: First and last name are both nil

Comment: did u check firestore scurity rules? You might have set write rule to false, if so then no user can write into database

Comment: @PeterHaddad i printed both of them out in the console so i know they are not nil

Comment: @ked What would that look like, Im not familiar with the security rules?

Comment: Is the uid getting added?

Comment: @PeterHaddad not to the firestore database but it is being added under the user section

Comment: security rules defines various access methods, where you can allow whether to allow users to give access to data or not, check the following link https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to the following:

```
// Add a new document with a generated ID
var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
ref = db.collection("users").addDocument(data: [
    "firstname": firstname,
    "lastname": lastname,
    "uid": result!.user.uid
]) { err in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error adding document: \(err)")
    } else {
        print("Document added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
    }
}
```

Using this print statement `print("Error adding document: \(err)")` you can know exactly what the error is.

Also change your security rules to the following:

```
// Allow read/write access to all users under any conditions
// Warning: **NEVER** use this rule set in production; it allows
// anyone to overwrite your entire database.
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You! Changing the security rules was the issue.

Comment: Only use these rules in development not in production

Comment: would i need a specific rule for new users or does "allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author_uid" work?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following different rules you can give access to users depending on the data

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  //allows all users to read and write, but dangerous as any one can flood your database
    match /public_collection/{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if true;
    }
//only read access
    match /public_read_collection/{document=**} {
        allow read: if true;
        allow write: if false;
    }
//prefered for storing users personal info, users can access only their data
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
//any authenticated user can access or write data
    match /posts/{documentId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```