# Data not stored in Firestore but the user's authentication info is available in Firebase authentication

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to add the user's data in Firestore while creating the user by 'createUserWithEmailAndPassword'. After submitting the button it not directed to the next page but the user is added in the Firebase authentication but not in the Firestore collection.

Below is the code used to add the user:

```
`auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _password, _name).then((value){
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc().set({
"email" : _email,
"userName" : _name,}).then((res)
{Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home');});});`
```

Error:

```
W/System  (30919): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/System  (30919): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/FirebaseAuth(30919): Notifying id token listeners about user ( qsKxr5mobGc44D8poFIINgZbLCK2 ).
D/FirebaseAuth(30919): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( qsKxr5mobGc44D8poFIINgZbLCK2 ).
E/flutter (30919): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(171)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_TypeError' has no instance getter 'message'.
E/flutter (30919): Receiver: Instance of '_TypeError'
E/flutter (30919): Tried calling: message
E/flutter (30919): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
E/flutter (30919): #1      _SignUpViewState.submit.<anonymous closure> (package:madrasdaily/sign_up_page.dart:84:24)
E/flutter (30919): #2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1244:30)
E/flutter (30919): #3      _SignUpViewState.submit (package:madrasdaily/sign_up_page.dart:83:9)
E/flutter (30919): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (30919): #4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:989:19)
E/flutter (30919): #5      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1098:38)
E/flutter (30919): #6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:183:24)
E/flutter (30919): #7      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:523:11)
E/flutter (30919): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:283:5)
E/flutter (30919): #9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:218:7)
E/flutter (30919): #10     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:476:9)
E/flutter (30919): #11     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:77:12)
E/flutter (30919): #12     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:122:9)
E/flutter (30919): #13     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:377:8)
E/flutter (30919): #14     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:120:18)
E/flutter (30919): #15     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:106:7)
E/flutter (30919): #16     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:219:19)
E/flutter (30919): #17     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:199:22)
E/flutter (30919): #18     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:157:7)
E/flutter (30919): #19     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:103:7)
E/flutter (30919): #20     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:87:7)
E/flutter (30919): #21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)
E/flutter (30919): #22     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (30919): #23     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (30919): #24     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:267:10)
E/flutter (30919): #25     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:176:5)
E/flutter (30919):
```

Flutter doctor:

```
elamparithi@Asifs-MacBook-Pro madrasdaily % flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.22.0, on Mac OS X 10.15.5 19F101, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.22.0 at /Users/elamparithi/Developer/flutter
    • Framework revision d261f1ef58 (4 months ago), 2020-08-03 00:59:36 -0400
    • Engine revision 083282e33b
    • Dart version 2.10.0 (build 2.10.0-4.0.dev 365525432a)



[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/elamparithi/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.6)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.6, Build version 11E708
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin installed
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • AOSP on IA Emulator (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
    • Web Server (web)             • web-server    • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 86.0.4240.198

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Authentication creates user but does not add their Info to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59442666/firebase-authentication-creates-user-but-does-not-add-their-info-to-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this similar SO question:

[Firebase Authentication creates user but does not add their Info to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59442666/firebase-authentication-creates-user-but-does-not-add-their-info-to-database)

They are recommending to add `print` statement in your code to check the error message.

Also you should check the security rules because this might solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your response, There is no issue with the security rules, I tried to print the error message it's not displaying anything, rather I am getting the same error, For your reference please check the below error message.

````

Comment: Can you please help me on this.

Comment: I was looking for the error ```Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null``` and found this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64727665/w-system-ignoring-header-x-firebase-locale-because-its-value-was-null)

Comment: I have already checked that. 
1. If the emulator is having an internet issue how it will load the data from Firestore.
2. I have already enabled the Email Authentication in the Firebase.

I couldn't able to find what is the issue.

Comment: You might be facing a delay in getting a response from FirebaseAuth. Does this error happens only on emulator? Are you facing these errors on actual devices.

Comment: Now the issue is fixed, i can able to save the data in the Firestore, I still couldn't figureout what might be the problem, because i dint change any code in this. This is my code.
`auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _password, _name)
                .then((value){
              FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc().set({
                "email" : _email,
                "userName" : _name,
              }).catchError((e){
                print("Error Msg: $e");
              });
            });
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home');`